# Toggling the dbc (arxml file) using system variable in Canoe

Tags: capl, canoe

I would like to know if the arxml file can be toggled using a sysvar in Canoe Capl based on need. (Or some way in start values/on start)

For ex:
`if (sysvar_x == 1) ⇒ Use arxml A`
`else ⇒ Use arxml B`

Thank you in advance for response

Comment: Things like this are typically done by changing the configuration via the COM API before starting the measurement. Is that an option?

Answer (score 0):

No, network database doesnt design work like that.
in general, CANoe support multiple database.
however, it take priority on the top one.
so, if there is a conflict/duplicate CAN ID/PDU, it will overlook from the later database.
so, the approach is to use 1 database for whole system. the database will interpret PDU, Signal group by Node/ECU.
if your 2 arxml meant for different ECU, just merge it or import both.
if your 2 arxml meant for same  ECU but different variant which require new signal, just merge it to same Node. you could add/define new PDU/signal there.